# add a new line after a specific line of a csv file in python3

Tags: python, csv, file-io, python-3.5

I am writing a python code in which a csv file is read and some information are written in. I should find one specific row and add a new line of data after it, at this stage. I have succeeded finding the row but I can not write the new line of data after it. Here is my attempt:

```
file = open('db.csv', 'r+')
table = csv.reader(file)
for row in table:
    if(row == ['tbl']):
        file.seek(len(row)) #this part is the problem I suppose
        break
table = csv.writer(file)
table.writerow(['1', '2'])
```

Comment: Do you want to replace all the remaning parts with newline + `1, 2` ?

Comment: @falsetru no no not at all. I just want that line to be added. nothing else should be changed in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `file.seek` / `file.tell` is tricky because `csv.reader` could read ahead; cannot tell exact file position that match current row.

Also inserting is not trivial; you need to remember remaing parts.

I would do it following way:

- creating another file for write
- write according to your need
- once done, replace the old file with new file

---

```
import csv
import shutil

with open('db.csv', 'r', newline='') as f, open('db.csv.temp', 'w', newline='') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
        if row == ['tbl']:
            writer.writerow([])  # empty line

shutil.move('db.csv.temp', 'db.csv')
```